# why willow can not login psql

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
when I use ubuntu 11.04 or 10.04 to install ros pr2 electric package, I try to use the psql database with the following link:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/sql_database/Tutorials/Installing%20a%20PostgreSQL%20Server
But unfortunately, willow can not log in psql.
1. sudo apt-get install postgresql
2. psql
3. CREATE ROLE willow LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE PASSWORD 'willow';
4.add the following into pg_hba.conf

## willow user can connect locally with password

local   all         willow                            md5
5. restart computer
6. psql --username willow --password --dbname postgres
The result is that:

root@ubuntu:~# psql --username willow --password --dbname postgres
Password for user willow:
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "willow"

Whether I use postgres or other os user to log in ubuntu, the result is the same.
It seems that I did not create the willow user.
What I do is just start the server use psql or psql --username postgres
Then I create the user and the \q.
So I didnot know how to solve this problem.
OR where can I get a good demo instruction to run the grasp and place demo on ubuntu 11.04 0r 10.04.
The problem is how to setup the database.
Best regards.
Zhenli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27714/why-willow-can-not-login-psql/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer by myself:
Though it does not work, but just forward your step, you can also get what you want to use the database.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database/Tutorials/Install%20the%20household_objects%20database%20on%20your%20local%20database%20server

---

Originally posted by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) with karma: 287 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0